# d3 transitions in Ember when Ember takes care of data joins

Tags: ember.js, d3.js

I like my d3 charts in Ember to be defined in my Handlebars files and avoid the d3.select() and data joins as much as possible. Rather than using d3's data joins, I want to rely on Ember's computed properties. In practice, in my d3 visualizations in Ember I tend to wrap my data points inside an `{{each}}` loop, and Ember takes care of updating the chart whenever the underlying data changes. This is all fine, but there is one important d3 feature that I feel like I'm losing that way, namely the [transitions](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/transition/). I like to have transitions between two states of the underlying data. Is there any way to, at the same time, rely on Ember for data joins (and avoid the d3.select().data() dance) AND somehow still be able to apply d3 transitions?

Here is an example code, where I'd like to transition a bar chart from one state into another when changing the height (it's kind of a trivial example, but I think it's illustrative). Thanks in advance for your help!

```
// bar-chart.js

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName: "svg",
    attributeBindings: ["width", "height"],
    width: 950,
    height: 600,
    padding: { top:..., bottom:..., left:..., right:... },
    transformG: function() {
        var padding = this.get("padding");
        return "translate(%@,%@)".fmt(padding.left, padding.top);
    }.property(),
    chartW: function() {
        ...
    }.property("width"),
    chartH: function() {
        ...
    }.property("height"),
    yScale: function() {
        var data = this.get("data");
        return d3.scale.linear().domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.value; })).range([...]);
    }.property("data", "chartH"),
    xScale: function() {
        ...
    }.property("data", "width"),
    actions: {
        // Some action that modifies the height of the svg
    }
});

// bar-chart.hbs

<g class="axis x"></g>
<g class="axis y"></g>
<g class="bars" {{bind-attr transform=transformG width=chartW height=chartH}}>
    {{#each d in data}}
        {{vertical-bar value=d.value timestamp=d.timestamp yScale=yScale xScale=xScale}}
    {{/each}}
<g>
```

Assume that the subcomponent `{{vertical-bar}}` takes care of computing a few attributes associated to each single bar.

Answer (score 0):

Although the d3 enter/update/exit paradigm can be confusing/cumbersome, it's really at the core of d3 and trying to override it but still use other parts of d3 (like `transition`) will probably get you in a lot of trouble.

For example:

d3 binds to svg elements a single time, but I think what you're doing here will rerender elements each time `data` changes and that's probably not what you want. If you tried to use `transition` and also updated your data in Ember at the same time, things would probably explode.

---

I'm familiar with the headaches of the "`d3.select().data()` dance" but in the end it usually meant I didn't understand the shape of my data very well. Is there some *technical* reason you don't want to do this? Or is an `each d in data` just easier conceptually?

### An Alternative

You may want to think about an intermediate set of `data` that is made for consumption by d3, but controlled by Ember. A strategy I'm using currently is create an an array of `ObjectProxy`s to wrap some custom properties, then passing it the whole thing d3:

`ObjectProxy.create({content: {timestamp: d.x, some_property: d.foo, type: "bar" }})`

When you update this intermediate set, you can simply pass the whole thing again to d3 and it will do the right thing given your enter/update/exit selections are setup correctly.

One tip to make sure this works is to set a unique ID on your datums and use that during selection:

`svg.selectAll("rect").data(@get("myData"), (d) -> d.get("id"))`

*Beware: coffeescript =)*

### Ember w/ D3

I think allowing Ember to control the data being input is about as far as you want to go before using D3 to do the rest, otherwise you're just mixing up responsibilities and you may as well roll your own graph library. The above alternative gives you a bit more control and adds computed properties to your datums which can be used like so:

`selection.transition().attr({x: (d) -> d.get("end_x")})` where `end_x` is something Ember has handled for you.

or: `.on("click", (d,i) => d.get("controller").transitionToRoute("myRoute", d.id))`

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I have a feeling that you are right, but am curious to see what other people think. The alternative pattern you suggest is actually more or less the one I was following until I thought about having Ember take over more responsibilities. There is no real technical reasons, just conceptually clearer to me, as you say. You got a good point about re-rendering, didn't think about that one. I wonder what approach the guys at Netflix use and if indeed they stick with the d3 joins instead of having Ember take that over. Thank you